# Jquery tabs content loading very slow

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a landing page with 5 tabs using Jquery. While the page is loading, ALL the content of the Tabs is showing on the front page untill the page loads completely and content will be placed and separated into the tabs. The current process is very slow. Is there an alternative? Only javascript is accepted where the landing page is hosted.

Comment: show us code and we see what's the problem

Comment: Hide all tabs except for the first. `display: none`

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this onDocumentLoad or onDocumentReady?

I would recommend doing this inside an `Init()` function...

```
$(Init);
function Init(){
   //set up tabs here
}
```

I would also suggest using CSS to hide all tab pages except the first as default.

```
.NonFirstTabPage
{
   display:none;
}
```

That way you should only see the first tab page when the page first loads, regardless of how long it takes to set-up the JQuery tab pages

Just remember, as great as Javascript/JQuery is, don't forget that the basics can solves quite a lot of simple needs to.

On another note, I abandoned any built-in tabbing functionality from JQuery as I found it to annoying to get it right (especially with styling) - it was fairy simple to create my own simple function to show and hide tab pages as needed.